# Take a variable from thymeleaf th:each

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Can i use variable charity from th:each in another block of code. For example

```
 <select class="select-field">
    <option th:each="charity : ${charities}" th:value="${charity.id}" th:text="${charity.name}"></option>
 </select>

<div>
   <p th:text="${'You selected '+ charity.name}">
<div>
```

Comment: No. Because, Thymeleaf is interpreted and rendered on the server-side. There is no more interaction, when the interpreted html is sent to browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Thymeleaf is rendered on the server-side, so to accomplish this, you would need to use `js` or `jQuery`. Something like the code below should do the trick.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // If you want the option's text.
    $('.select-field').on('change', function() {
        $('p').text("You selected " + $(this).find('option:selected').text()));
    })

    // If you want the option's value.
    $('.select-field').on('change', function() {
        $('p').text("You selected " + $(this).val()));
    })
})
```

**UPDATE**

If you would like to add more information from your charity object to your options, you could use `th:attr`. So, for example, if you want the charity's description and image name, then you could do something like the following.

**HTML**

```
<select class="select-field">
    <option th:each="charity : ${charities}" th:value="${charity.id}" th:text="${charity.name}" th:attr="data-description=${charity.description}, data-image=${charity.image}"></option>
</select>
```

Then, you could just get each attribute value using jQuery `.attr()` function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.select-field').on('change', function() {
        var selectedOption = $(this).find('option:selected');
        var name = $(selectedOption).text();
        var id = $(selectedOption).val();
        var description = $(selectedOption).attr('data-description');
        var imageName = $(selectedOption).attr('data-image');
        // Find your image by id.
        var image = $('#myImage');

        // Set your new image.
        $(image).attr('src','/img/'+ imageName));
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks, it works.But what to do, if i want to display description and image of selected charity? Сan i get these from my DB using Jquery?

Comment: I jus edited my answer. I would use Thymeleaf `th:attr` and then jQuery `.attr()` to fetch each one of those fields.

Comment: I edited the jQuery code, so that you can see how to change an image src using jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, you can make following change to div tag:

```
<div class="display-class">
   <p></p>
<div>
```

This will help identify particular *div*

Then you can use jQuery to display the name of the selected option.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.select-field').on("change", function() {        
    var selectedOption = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    $div = $('.display-class');
    $p = $div.find('p');
    $p.text("You selected: " + selectedOption);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works.But what to do, if i want to display description and image of selected charity? Сan i get these from my DB using Jquery?